# Allow PHP script to SSH into multiple servers

Tags: javascript, php, for-loop, ssh, phpseclib

I have a CSV file that sits on a Raspberry PI and outputs:

```
2018-03-22 12:43:21,NM_Test.h264,-2
```

On my host server I have a PHP script that takes the output from the CSV file and displays it as a HTML table on my webpage:

```
$command = "ssh -p 97 -i /var/www/html/test.rsa pi@192.168.xxx.xxx tail -1 /var/log/playlog.csv";
$output = exec($command);
$array = explode(',',$output);

echo '<div class="container"><table class="table table-striped">
 <tr>
 <th>Status</th>
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>Date/Time</th>
 <th>Playing</th>
 <th>Error</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>';
 if(in_array('0', $array, true)){
  echo '<div id="circleGreen"></div>';
 }

 if (in_array('-2', $array, true)){
  echo '<div id="circleRed"></div>';
 }
 echo'</td>
 <td>Guildford test</td>
 <td>'.$array[0].'</td>
 <td>'.$array[1].'</td>
 <td>';
```

This method works for one SSH connection, but how can I run the SSH command multiple times for connecting to different PIs?

I thought about creating a txt file and saving each SSH command in there, and then have my PHP script read/execute each command line by line:

```
// example txt file 
ssh -p 97 -i test.rsa pi@xxx.xxx.xxx.61 
ssh -p 97 -i test2.rsa pi@xxx.xxx.xxx.62 
// and so on..
// only the rsa key name & IP address changes
```

But I'd like a more efficient solution to my problem.

***Update***

As recommended I used the phpsec library to SSH onto the PI:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('phpseclib1.0.10/Crypt/RSA.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('192.xxx.xxx.xxx', 97);
$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('test.rsa'));

if (!$ssh->login('pi', $key)){
 exit ('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

But by doing so I still have to type the IP address as well as the RSA key name. I'd like a solution that allows me to quickly ssh into multiple PIs and execute the exec command.

One possible solution I can think of is allowing my script to read the known_hosts file? Is that possible?

Comment: I would suggest using PHPSecLib2.0, it's way nicer then anything else for SSH (sFTP) IMO>

Comment: Could you kindly show me an example on how I can use it? There's not much documentation on it

Comment: There is plenty of documentation you just have to know where to look Like [HERE](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/2.0/examples.html) It's about 1000x easier to use then the ssh2 extension. Also one problem with exec is that its not an interactive shell, each command is stateless by itself. you have to/could try to use ssh2 extension and last I knew it was broken for windows.

Comment: As a bonus, it also does `AES` `SSL` (like making self singed certs) and many other cryptographic things.  The only thing I find it lacking in is no PGP encryption, but than again there isn't really any easy to use libraries for that..

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response and for the link. I managed to get phpseclib woking! I will update my answer so you can see what I did

Comment: Please see my updated question, although I got the phpseclib working I still cant figure out a solution to my problem, I'd appreciate any feedback from you.

Comment: Actually, after thinking about it.  I would make a config file that has a list of the IP address, and login credentials ( usernam, password or RSA key).  And then your script just loads that and loops though it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I would do...  (make my own config file)

```
//you don't need the ( ) for include/require
//without these files it wont work, should be require then. Classes only need be included 1 time
require_once 'Net/SSH2.php';
require_once 'phpseclib1.0.10/Crypt/RSA.php';
//when you include/require like this it puts the content into the variable
//when that content is a PHP array, it puts it in the variable. This needs to be included each time the script is ran
$config = require 'config.php';
$log = 'logfile.txt';

if(is_array($config)){
    foreach($config as $cred){
        $ssh = new Net_SSH2($cred['ip'], $cred['port']); //i think this is port?
        $key = new Crypt_RSA();
        $key->loadKey($cred['key']);

        if (!$ssh->login('pi', $key)){
             //logging with file_put_contants, Append mode, exclusive lock is more race condition safe then an open file handle.
            file_put_contants($log, "[".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."]Login Failed for {$cred['ip']}\n", FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX);
            continue;
            //or you can echo it, but you don't want to kill the whole thing if one fails /maybe?
        }
        //echo or save to file etc.
        echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
    }
}
```

Then in `config.php`

```
return [
    [
        "ip" : "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 97,
        "key" : 'ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3MAA...c3=',
    ]
    [ ... ]
];
```

You can even modify the config file programmatically by doing something like this

```
  file_put_contants('config.php', '<?php'."\nreturn ".var_export($config,true).";\n");
```

The `var_export` function outputs in a PHP compatible format, ie. syntactically correct.  Then the second argument of it is return as string.  So this converts the array to a string that is the same format as a valid PHP array.  Then it's pretty trivial to add `<?php` and the `return` and then the ending `;` and save it.

Obviously, I wouldn't suggest saving any "end User" input this way. And you will probably want to prevent access to this file. (eg. put outside the webroot)

Comment: Sure, no problem